# How to echo the translated custom field?

Tags: functions, custom-field, hooks

I have this function to echo the 'my_custom_field' value, and it works fine:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' , 'my_function');

function my_function(){

    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_custom_field', true ); 

}
```

But this only prints the value. I need to also print the translated title of this custom field. How can get this?

Comment: Which plugin you use for translate title ?

Comment: @Nefro I use WPML

Comment: did you try "echo get_post_meta( get_the_title(), 'my_custom_field', true ); "?

Comment: @rudtek I tried it, but print nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you do this:

```
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '', true);
print_r($meta);
```

or

```
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my_custom_field');
print_r($meta);
```

the first will pull all custom post type on the current post, and the second restricts to the field.  You should get an array and then you'll know which item in your array is the field title you're looking to pull.  then you can use that to return title

Comment: I get the id but now how do I print the title?

Comment: can you tell me what is returned when you print the meta array?  That will help me know your meta structure and then we can get it to print what you need